# Why positive diagonal entries in Cholesky decomposition?

Tags: matrix-decomposition

I don't understand why L must have strictly positive diagonal entries in Cholesky decomposition?:

$A = L*L^{T}$

Comment: The solution is not unique if this is not required.

Comment: You could simply let $S=-L$ and have $A=SS^{T}$, but the resulting factorization wouldn’t be a Cholesky factorization.  This element of the definition of the Cholesky factorization makes the factorization unique.

Comment: Aside from the fact that $L_{j,j} =  \sqrt{ A_{j,j} - \sum_{k=1}^{j-1} L_{j,k}^{2} } $?

Comment: @HansEngler, your comment as a one line answer would be the easiest complete solution. The only thing I would add is a reference that says as much.